# Ashx handler's processrequest function is not called

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, httphandler

I am writing a handler to process a resource and I am facing an issue, when the implemented IHttpHandler Class is written under a namespace.

Please find the code

**Not working scenario**

Web.config:

```
<add name="ResourceHandler" type="PublicSite.Classes.Handlers.ResourceEndpoint, PublicSite" path="Resource.ashx" verb="*" />
```

Property: `PublicSite.Classes.Handlers.ResourceEndpoint.IsReusable=False`

Issue: Constructor is hit and the ProcessRequest is not invoked. Constructs the object of the class, ie., Constructor is hit , however fails by 404 before the processrequest is invoked.

**Working Scenario**

Web.config:

```
<add name="ResourceHandler" type="ResourceEndpoint,PublicSite" path="Resource.ashx" verb="*" />
```

Class: `PublicSite.Classes.Handlers.ResourceEndpoint.IsReusable=True`

Constructor is hit and fails by 404 before the processrequest is invoked.

Second time when we request for the handler, it straight away uses the constructed object  so construcotr is not invoked and the ProcessRequest is invoked directly. By the way  in the second call the handler is working.

I dont require the reusable property. 
Can some one help me to find the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using an actual .ashx file as well as registering it in the web config?

Comment: It might be that, even if the handler is in a namespace, you only need the class name, without the namespace, in the config line?

Comment: Which version of IIS are you using ? for 6 and below you need to register the handler under <system.web> but for 7 and above it's in the <system.webServer> section in web.config

Comment: I am sorry, I have updated the question. This is not a cause of the namespace. The processrequest is not invoked and 404 is issued for an unknown reason.

Comment: @sh1rts I have updated the question with the issue details. I tried in iis 7.5 and 8.5 , the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you confirm to me that your web.config and handler itself looks like the following ? (This is from a project hosted under IIS 7.5)

web.config: -

```
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="customerHandler" 
           preCondition="integratedMode" 
           verb="*" 
           path="customerHandler.ashx"
           type="GlassCMS.HttpHandlers.CustomerHandler, GlassCMS"/>
.
.
.
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

HttpHandler: -

```
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://{redacted.com}/json-http-handlers/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    public class CustomerHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            string json = string.Empty;

            // code to do whatever here...

            context.Response.Write(json);
        }
```

I can include the JavaScript as well if you want (or you can post yours here). This example above is from working code.